# How does c++ cin>>x work

Tags: c++

In C when we want to input an integer for example, we can use `scanf()`.
The variable to which our input is to be saved is passed as a pointer, and this makes sense for the function needs the address for this variable otherwise the inputted value would lost as soon as the function returned.

How can (in C++) `cin>>x`, which I understand to be `cin.operator>>(x)` work if I don't pass an address to it?

Comment: C++ has references, which are basically pointers but without the `&` syntax.

Comment: Read up on *pass by reference* in your favorite C++ text book.  The `operator>>()` method accepts parameters by *reference*.

Comment: I hadn't learned about references yet, but now I understand, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"How can C++ cin>>x , which I understand to be cin.operator>>(x), work if I do not pass an address to it?"*

It's because the signature of the

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, <type>& obj);
                                              // ^
```

function takes a **reference parameter** for `obj`.

A C++ reference somehow replaces passing pointers to supplied parameters around, but also needs to be initialized with a valid address.

That's implemented for any primitive types, and some of the complex types (as e.g. `std::string`) of the standard library.